# Remove "http://" from URL string

Tags: php, string

I am using a bit.ly shortener for my custom domain. It outputs `http://shrt.dmn/abc123`; however, I'd like it to just output `shrt.dmn/abc123`.

Here is my code.

```
//automatically create bit.ly url for wordpress widgets
function bitly()
{
  //login information
  $url = get_permalink();  //for wordpress permalink
  $login = 'UserName'; //your bit.ly login
  $apikey = 'API_KEY'; //add your bit.ly APIkey
  $format = 'json'; //choose between json or xml
  $version = '2.0.1';
  //generate the URL
  $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$apikey.'&format='.$format;

  //fetch url
  $response = file_get_contents($bitly);
//for json formating
  if(strtolower($format) == 'json')
  {
    $json = @json_decode($response,true);
    echo $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
  }
  else //for xml formatting
  {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    echo 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your following line:

```
 echo $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
```

for this one:

```
 echo substr( $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'], 7);
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as it is supposed to be url and if there is `http://` - then this solution is the simplest possible:

```
$url = str_replace('http://', '', $url);
```

Comment: Thank you, zerkms. I'm not entirely knowledgeable when it comes to PHP. Where would I put that line of code?

Comment: @Christopher Burton: perhaps after `$url = get_permalink();` line

Comment: Now it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Used @Nelson's solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

You want to do a preg_replace.

```
$variable = preg_replace( '/http:\/\//', '', $variable ); (this is untested, so you might also need to escape the : character ).
```

you can also achieve the same effect with $variable = str_replace('http://', '', $variable )

Comment: RE is so complex for such simple thing.

Comment: I downvoted for the "this is untested, .." bit.  Please take the time to ensure that your solution will actually work prior to posting it as an answer.